# Web scraping using Beautiful Soup separating HTML and Javascript and CSS

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web page which comprises of Javascript, CSS and HTML. Now this web page also has some text. When I open the web page using the file handler on running the `soup.get_text()` command I would only like to view the HTML portion and nothing else. Is it possible to do this?

The current source code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup(open("/home/Desktop/try.html"))

print soup.get_text()
```

What do I change to get only the HTML portion in a web page and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the contents of the tags that hold the unwanted text (or style attributes).

Here is some code (tested in basic cases)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/home/Desktop/try.html"))

# Clear every script tag
for tag in soup.find_all('script'):
    tag.clear()

# Clear every style tag
for tag in soup.find_all('style'):
    tag.clear()

# Remove style attributes (if needed)
for tag in soup.find_all(style=True):
    del tag['style']

print soup.get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by *get*. Dmralev's answer will clear the other tags, which will work fine. However, `<HTML>` is a tag within the `soup`, so

```
print soup.html.get_text()
```

should also work, with fewer lines, assuming *portion* means that the HTML is seperate from the rest of the code (ie the other code is not within `<HTML>` tags).